# How to switch rendering order for Vue components on mobile view?

Tags: css, vue.js

I have 2 Vue components, dividing the page into 2 parts. Left side, and right side. I'm using this two on every page, like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="page-body">
    <left-side>
      <p class="text" >{{ $t('about') }}</p>
    </left-side>
    <right-side>
      <p class="slogen bottom">{{ $t('slogen') }}</p>
    </right-side>
  </div>
</template>
```

But there is a special case, when this two components should switch place, to render the right-side before the left-side, when using responsive mobile design. What would be the way to accomplish this behavior? I'm using Vue 2.3.3

Comment: if not possible using css, you could add a condition `v-if` which checks the mediaquery and retruns <left> <right> or <right><left>

Comment: You can look at the Bootstrap grid system, especially the part about reordering https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp

Answer (score 5):

This is a CSS question. Lay them out in a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) and use the [order property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) in a media query to change the order.

The example below will swap the two colored areas when the display width is between 300 and 600 pixels.

```css
.page-body {
  display: flex;
}

left-side,
right-side {
  background-color: #fdc;
  display: block;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

right-side {
  background-color: #cdf;
  text-align: right;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 500px) {
  left-side {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page-body">
  <left-side>
    <p class="text">{{ $t('about') }}</p>
  </left-side>
  <right-side>
    <p class="slogen bottom">{{ $t('slogen') }}</p>
  </right-side>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use Vuetify, you can easily do that with the [order property](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-col/#props-order-lg):

```
<v-row>
    <v-col class="col-11 col-md-6" order-md="2">
        <p>On mobile: on the left; otherwise on the right</p>
    </v-col>
    <v-col class="col-11 col-md-6" order-md="1">
        <p>On mobile: on the right; on tablet/desktop(-> md) on the left</p>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without flex, you can achieve this with floats, here is short example:

```css
.right, .left {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: black 1px solid;
  width: 50%;
  height: 130px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .left, .right {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  second
</div>

<div class="left">
  first
</div>
```

Comment: You can still use flex and use the `order` property. Floats aren't necessary.

Comment: Sure, but you might need IE9 support

Comment: "when using responsive mobile design". No mobile device has IE.

Comment: responsive to me does not mean it's on mobile device only. You can still open the page on some old win XP laptop let's say only on half of the screen and there you have it ....
Even IE11 does not fully support flexboxes
http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: I understand, but in the question it specifically mentions mobile responsive. IE11 has bugs, yes, but none of which affect the `order` property. In regards to older browser support, unless the question specifically asks for older browser support, SO answers will generally not include it. I mean, even MS gave up support for IE9 in January 2016. NOW, after all this is said, your answer is still is valid solution - so take an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

**If anyone uses `vuetify` and wants to change the order of appearance of `v-flex` elements**

---

**In Large Display, i.e. Tablet to Laptop:**

Use a `scoped css` like the following to reverse the order row-wise `|A|B|` will become `|B|A|`:

```
.layout.row.wrap {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
      }
```

**In Mobile View, changing the order of column:**

Should use a `scoped css` such as follows to reverse the order when they are shown in a mobile devices:

```
@media (max-width: 425px) {
  .layout.row.wrap {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

Here, `max-width` can be set to any convenient value to meet the requirement. If only in one layout the reverse ordering is needed but normal order in all other cases, then the specific layout can be separated in a component where this custom styling may be applied.

[More about Ordering Flex Items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

Comment: this is actually done using css, it should apply to any layout system that is based on `flex`